# objective-c properties - getters and setters

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, getter-setter

In a UIView subclass I have this property:

```
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat scale;

#define DEFAULT_SCALE 0.90
```

and this getter and setter:

```
-(CGFloat)scale
{
    if (!self.scale) {
        return DEFAULT_SCALE;
    }else{
        return self.scale;
    }
}

-(void)setScale:(CGFloat)scale
{
    if (scale != self.scale) {
        self.scale = scale;
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }

}
```

This isn't correct, because for example checking self.scale in the getter causes an infinite loop. What is the proper way to write the getter and setter so that I don't get infinite looping?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should be able to access the ivar directly as `_scale`.  Your getter/setter would then look like:

Update: As @wattson12 points out in the comments below you will need to add an `@synthesize` to your implementation.

```
@synthesize scale = _scale;

-(CGFloat)scale
{
    if (!_scale) {
        return DEFAULT_SCALE;
    }else{
        return _scale;
    }
}

-(void)setScale:(CGFloat)scale
{
    if (scale != _scale) {
        _scale = scale;
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }

}
```

Comment: I get "use of undeclared identifier '_scale'"

Comment: Did you use an `@synthesize` for your property?  Did you create a `scale` variable in your interface?

Comment: if you override both the setter and getter you wont get the auto synthesize feature, you will need to add @synthesize scale = _scale;

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I usually don't have to synthesize because Xcode does it automatically.

Comment: If you override the getter and setter, there is no need for @synthesize. Just add your own ivar and have the methods use the ivar.

Answer (score 3):

[Dot notation can be a tad misleading at first.](http://weblog.bignerdranch.com/83-83/)

### The Setter

In the line you've posted here

```
self.scale = scale;
```

you're not assigning to a local variable.  In fact, you're sending the message `-setScale:` to `self`.  This line is equivalent to

```
[self setScale:scale];
```

Since you're calling `-setScale:` from within `-setScale:`, you're getting this infinite recursion.

What you need to do is set an instance variable in your setter (rather than calling your setter from within itself).  Normally, just by writing

```
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat scale;
```

you've created an instance variable `_scale`.  **However**, since you also overrode both `-scale` and `-setScale:`, this instance variable will not be created.  Therefore, you'll need to add the instance variable yourself.  In your class' declaration `@interface` (or alternatively, in a [class extension](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/occategories.html) `@interface`)

```
//If adding the instance variable to the class declaration:
@interface MyClass : Superclass
{
    //....
    CGFloat _scale;
}
//....
@end
```

After having done this, it's enough to change the line to

```
_scale = scale;
```

### The Getter

There are two other problematic line you've posted, these in the getter.  The first is

```
return self.scale;
```

inside `- (CGFloat)scale`.  Similarly to before, this dot notation does not mean what you may think it means.  In fact, it means

```
return [self scale];
```

As before, this is causing infinite recursion.  The second is

```
if (!self.scale) {
```

It is a problem for just the same reason: the expression `self.scale`, when evaluated is [self scale].  Again, this causes infinite recursion.  The fix to both of these is to replace `self.scale` with `_scale` leaving you with this getter:

```
- (CGFloat)scale
{
    if (!_scale) {//Since CGFloat is not an object, this means <<if (_scale == 0) {>>
        return DEFAULT_SCALE;
    } else {
        return _scale
    }
}
```

### A Better Way

You're doing much more work here than you really ought to be.  It would be much better to take advantage of your initializer:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    {
        self.scale = DEFAULT_SCALE;
    }
}
```

This will guarantee that if `scale` is not set, it will return `DEFAULT_SCALE`.  This allows you to entirely eliminate the getter (and, consequently, the `@synthesize`).  Since you're calling `-setNeedsDisplay` in the setter, you'll still need it.

```
- (void)setScale:(CGFloat)scale
{
    if (_scale != scale) {
        _scale = scale;
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the explanation. This is what I figured, but I didn't know that writing your own getter/setter means you have to synthesize the property.

Comment: @soleil I highly recommend you try out what I put under the heading "A Better Way".  You're doing quite a bit more work than you really need to be.

Comment: Why does removing only the getter eliminate the @synthesize?

Comment: @soleil You only needed the `@synthesize` because you had overridden both the setter **and** the getter.  Once you eliminate one of these overrides, you get the `_scale` instance variable created for you automatically.

Answer (score 2):

well I can think of about 3 ways to do this and be 0 aware.

```
@interface someClass
{
    BOOL useCustomScale;
}
@property float scale;
@end
@implimentation someClass
-(float)scale
{
    if(useCustomScale)
    {return scale;}
    return defaultScale;
}
-(void) setScale: (float)someScale
{
    useCustomScale = YES;
    scale = someScale
}
```

else you could use an NSNumber for backing the scale value...
else you could initialize the scale to -1 and make that an illegal value in the setter.
0 is typically a very bad thing to use for your test because you may very well want 0 to be valid value.